# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator

Tags: android

I have a filename in my code as :

```
String NAME_OF_FILE="//sdcard//imageq.png";
FileInputStream fis =this.openFileInput(NAME_OF_FILE); // 2nd line
```

I get an error on 2nd line :

> 05-11 16:49:06.355: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4570): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File //sdcard//imageq.png contains a path separator

I tried this format also:

```
String NAME_OF_FILE="/sdcard/imageq.png";
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This method opens a file in the private data area of the application. You cannot open any files in subdirectories in this area or from entirely other areas using this method. So use the constructor of the `FileInputStream` directly to pass the path with a directory in it.

Comment: Please provide some example for this

Comment: Your answer is confusing; OP is using a FileInputStream

Comment: provide example

Comment: Please expound on the answer.

Comment: this is the wrong answer - please see the answer below

Answer (score 98):

The solution is:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (new File(NAME_OF_FILE));  // 2nd line
```

The openFileInput method doesn't accept path separators.

Don't forget to

```
fis.close();
```

at the end.

Comment: Given that one can use `FileInputStream` like this, why choose to use `openFileInput`?

Comment: This should be the correctly marked answer because it provides a clear example.

Comment: Simple solutions are the best one. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

`openFileInput()` doesn't accept paths, only a file name
if you want to access a path, use `File file = new File(path)` and corresponding `FileInputStream`

Answer (score 5):

I got the above error message while trying to access a file from Internal Storage using `openFileInput("/Dir/data.txt")` method with subdirectory `Dir`.

You cannot access sub-directories using the above method.

Try something like:

```
FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream (new File("/Dir/data.txt"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use path with directory separators directly, but you will
have to make a file object for every directory.

NOTE: This code makes directories, yours may not need that...

```
File file= context.getFilesDir();
file.mkdir();

String[] array=filePath.split("/");
for(int t=0; t< array.length -1 ;t++)
{
    file=new File(file,array[t]);
    file.mkdir();
}

File f=new File(file,array[array.length-1]);

RandomAccessFileOutputStream rvalue = new RandomAccessFileOutputStream(f,append);
```

Comment: What ? `File f = new File(fileDirPath); f.mkdirs();` Please edit

Answer (score 1):

```
String all = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                all = all + strLine;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("notes_err", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = context.getFilesDir(); 
file.mkdir();
String[] array = filePath.split("/"); 
for(int t = 0; t < array.length - 1; t++) {
    file = new File(file, array[t]); 
    file.mkdir();
}
File f = new File(file,array[array.length- 1]); 
RandomAccessFileOutputStream rvalue = 
    new RandomAccessFileOutputStream(f, append);
```

Comment: Same answer as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this type of error by making a directory in the onCreate event, then accessing the directory by creating a new file object in a method that needs to do something such as save or retrieve a file in that directory, hope this helps!

```
 public class MyClass {    

 private String state;
 public File myFilename;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//create your directory the user will be able to find
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        myFilename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/My Directory");
        if (!myFilename.exists()) {
            myFilename.mkdirs();
        }
    }
 }

 public void myMethod {

 File fileTo = new File(myFilename.toString() + "/myPic.png");  
 // use fileTo object to save your file in your new directory that was created in the onCreate method
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
var dir = File(app.filesDir, directoryName)
if(!dir.exists()){
    currentCompanyFolder.mkdir()
}
var directory = app.getDir(directoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val file = File(directory, fileName)
file.outputStream().use {
    it.write(body.bytes())
}
```