# How to upload file with relative path

Tags: android, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator)

I am trying to upload a file from my sdcard, file path url="sdcard/Folder/test.doc". I am using the following code to upload to server.

```
String url = path.getText().toString();
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(url);
```

It is giving me error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-19 01:19:39.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7459): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /sdcard/download/ABC.pdf contains a path separator.
```

Can some one please tell me how to get it done?

Comment: Yup. It is duplicate of it. Can you give me syntax how to access it. The duplicate one didn't provide any code.

Answer (score 0):

`openFileInput(url);` can not open file stored on sdcard. this method is used to *Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for reading.*

you must use `new File(path)` method to create or open a file. then use appropriate InputStream. can refer below syntax..

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
```

Comment: I am trying this code
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f_path = new File(dir, url);
InputStream  fis = null;
fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f_path));
when I run this it is returning me java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/sdcard/download/xyx.txt (No such file or directory)
Can you tell me what is wrong with it?