# Reading a file from Android device

Tags: android, file-upload

Continuing my previous post, [upload file with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968618/how-to-upload-file-with-relative-path) I tried to run using

```
url = '/mnt/sdcard/download/XYZ.txt';
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f_path = new File(dir, url);
InputStream  fis = null;
fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f_path));
```

But is throwing me errors when I run this from my Android device.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/download/XYZ.txt (No such file or directory)
```

The output of f_path is '/mnt/sdcard/download/XYZ.txt'

Where is the problem, and how to fix it? I can observe that it is adding mnt/sdcard to f_path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992722/how-to-find-path-of-internal-phone-storage-personal-data-internal-sd-card-ext. May this link will help you.

Comment: Do you want to copy the content of XYZ file.?

Comment: yes. I need to copy. But the problem is with path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with that code .

```
url = '/mnt/sdcard/download/XYZ.txt';
File f_path = new File(url);
InputStream  fis = null;
fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f_path));
```

The exception had come coz  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` it self give equal to

```
/mnt/sdcard
```

Good luck !!

Comment: yup. I got this. But as of knew about Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); is there any impact in removing that?

Comment: No there will not impact of it , as android directory stander is same for each device

Answer (score 1):

On your url variable, only use the relative path:

`url = "/download/XYZ.txt"`

The `/mnt/sdcard` will come from your `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Comment: the url value I mentioned is returned to me by a file picker activity. So do I need to trim to get the url you mentioned?

Comment: If the file picker is returning the full path, create a file only having the url parameter. `File f_path = new File(url);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that as following :

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File file = new File(sdcard, "/download/XYZ.txt");
```

That will automatially get your file..

After that you can use it as following:

```
InputStream  fis = null;
fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

That will get your file's path perfectly!!

Comment: It didn't work. Actually I am browsing the file into a edittext field. When I select the file, it returns the file path so that I can use to upload.

Comment: if you want to show file path into editext then of course you can get it using "file.getAbsolutePath()" function after writing:
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard, "/download/XYZ.txt");

Comment: for my requirement I cannot give the hard coded value for file("/download/XYZ.txt". I am trying to browse through my mobile to select the file. Please look at my code. I need to upload the file after that.

Comment: I tried this and it worked.InputStream  fis = null;fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(url); I removed first two lines of code.