# Can't access XML file in project directory

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, file-io

Strange situation here and its driving me insane. I have a skeleton XML file in my project root directory and I want to read it into my program and modify it based on the users input. I'm getting a file not found exception and I can't understand why. My project is called customerCreator. The XML file is at:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CustomerCreator\skeleton.xml
```

My Java source file is at:

C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CustomerCreator\src\java\org\user\r6CustomerCreator\parsers\XMLParser.java

EDIT: Using the absolute filepath causes the follwing error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null

```
public class XMLParser {

    public XMLParser(Map paramMap) {
        parseXML(paramMap);
    }

    private void parseXML(Map<String, String> paramMap) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        Document document = null;

            try {
                builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }

            try {
                document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("skeleton.xml"));
            } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.print(document);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
document = builder.parse(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/skeleton.xml"));
```

It works for me

[image: Netbeans]

Comment: Thanks but see my comment to Franck below. Same result!

Comment: Put your file in resources folder in netbeans and try again.

Comment: So I put it in C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\r6CustomerCreator\src\resources\skeleton.xml but getting the same issue

Comment: It works. I don't know what I was doing wrong so I rewrote the class and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should try to use the fullpath. If it works it means that your active solution directory is not the one you think.

Comment: Tried that and got the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null` but I know for sure that the file is not empty

Answer (score 1):

well, try to change your file extension and give it another try. If it works i will advice you to use dedicated xml classes in order to read from your file. try .txt extension

also have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator). Looks like you should use the following syntax `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (new File(NAME_OF_FILE));`

Comment: Thanks Franck but still doesn't work with either suggestion :(