# IllegalArgumentException: File contains a path separator Android

Tags: java, android, file, exception, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to write to an output file on my HTC One and get the following message in the LogCat:

> 11-21 08:05:18.228: W/System.err(6609): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/com.example.pattern1/myfile.txt contains a path separator

The source code is given below:

```
    protected void writeToFile(String string){

    File patternDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/com.example.pattern1/myfile.txt");
    patternDirectory.mkdirs();

    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(patternDirectory.getAbsolutePath().toString(), Context.MODE_APPEND);
      outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
      TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bottomMidText);
      t.setText(patternDirectory.getAbsolutePath().toString());
      outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would appreciate if someone can help identify the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator)

Comment: @Talal Saleem which line gives you the error?

Comment: @timrau Your link is the input case, this is about output. Minor, I know.

Answer (score 20):

The openFileInput method will not  accept path separators.('/')

it accepts only the name of the file which you want to open/access. so change the statement

```
outputStream = openFileOutput(patternDirectory.getAbsolutePath().toString(), Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

to

```
outputStream = new FileOutputStream (new File(patternDirectory.getAbsolutePath().toString()), true); // true will be same as Context.MODE_APPEND
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm not sure how I would've gotten to this answer if you had not posted it.  I couldn't save to my file located in internal files directory (getFilesDir()) otherwise.  I'm confused why the supposedly Google-documented way of using openFileOutput doesn't work.  Very confusing of Google docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int) ).

Answer (score 1):

One problem may be the fact that you do:
 `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/com.example.pattern1/myfile.txt"`

You create a directory that has name myfile.txt