# IllegalArgumentException: File contains a path separator Android

Tags: android, runtime-error, illegalargumentexception, path-separator

I am searching in google and can not find a true answer to my question !
my question is same as [him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053487/illegalargumentexception-file-contains-a-path-separator-android) but his want MODE_APPEND and i want MODE_PRIVATE for my file.how should i do ?

this is my code :

```
public boolean saveCustomButtonInfo (Context context, Vector<DocumentButtonInfo> info) throws Exception{
    String path= context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "Load";
    File file = new File(path);

    if(! file.exists()){
        file.mkdir();
        //Toast.makeText(context,file.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    path=path+"/DocumentActivityCustomButtonsInfo.obj";
    try{
        FileOutputStream out=context.openFileOutput(path,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream outObject=new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        outObject.writeObject(info);
        outObject.flush();
        out.close();
        outObject.close();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use paths with slashes (`/`) with `openFileOutput()`. More importantly, you are trying to combine both `getFilesDir()` and `openFileOutput()`, which is unnecessary and is causing this problem.

Change your code to:

```
public void saveCustomButtonInfo (Context context, List<DocumentButtonInfo> info) throws Exception {
    File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "Load");

    if(! dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    File f = new File(dir, "DocumentActivityCustomButtonsInfo.obj");
    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream outObject=new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    outObject.writeObject(info);
    outObject.flush();
    out.getFD().sync();
    outObject.close();
}
```

Of note:

- `Vector` has been obsolete for ~15 years
- Never use concatenation to build filesystem paths; use the proper `File` constructor
- There is no point in catching an exception only to just re-throw it
- There is no point in returning a `boolean` that is always `true`
- Call `getFD().sync()` on a `FileOutputStream` to confirm all bytes are written to disk

Comment: thank you for the  best answer . i know Vector has been obsolete but thats easier than ArrayList . and the boolean value for checking the true operation .