# Bitmap display using file path

Tags: android, file, android-bitmap

I have certain set of image urls which I need to download and store in internal storage.

Code for downloading and saving image is :

```
   public void callDownloadImageAsync(int pos) {
        String baseDir = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        if (allImagesArr.size() > pos) {
            try {
                int count;
                String imageUrl = allImagesArr.get(pos);

                URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                Utility.printMessage("imageUrl..." + imageUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                if (Utility.getToken(this).length() > 0) {
                    Utility.printMessage("@@@ my header for photos " + Utility.getToken(this));
                    try {
                        connection.setRequestProperty("X-CSRF-TOKEN", Utility.getToken(this));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                connection.connect();
                String PATH;
                File imgFile;

//                if (allImagesFileNameArr.get(pos).startsWith("lead_")) {
                if (allImagesFileNameArr.get(pos).startsWith("/")) {
                    imgFile = new File(allImagesFileNameArr.get(pos));
                    PATH = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
                } else {
                    File folder = new File(baseDir + allImagesFileNameArr.get(pos)).getParentFile();
                    if (!folder.exists())
                        folder.mkdirs();
                    String imageName = allImagesFileNameArr.get(pos);
                    imageName = imageName.substring(imageName.lastIndexOf("/"));

                    imgFile = new File(folder, imageName);
                    PATH = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
                }

//                }

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(PATH);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    //                    publishProgress ((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
//                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
//                Utility.saveToInternalStorage(context, bitmap, PATH);

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

                Utility.printMessage("image saved...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Utility.logException(e);
            }

            callDownloadImageAsync(pos + 1);
        }
    }
```

I get the messege "image saved" in the log.
But when i try to read the bitmap using the path I am getting the following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/user/0/com.app.los_pdapp/files/lead_1/PRAPPL_profile.jpg contains a path separator
04-25 14:28:43.024 21208-21208/com.app.los_pdapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2413)
04-25 14:28:43.024 21208-21208/com.app.los_pdapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:504)
04-25 14:28:43.024 21208-21208/com.app.los_pdapp W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:193)
04-25 14:28:43.024 21208-21208/com.app.los_pdapp W/System.err:     at com.app.los_pdapp.Util.Utility.readBitmap(Utility.java:977)
04-25 14:28:43.024 21208-21208/com.app.los_pdapp W/System.err:     at com.app.los_pdapp.Fragments.PD.Applicant.DetailView.bindView(DetailView.java:154)
04-25 14:28:43.024 21208-21208/com.app.los_pdapp W/System.err:     at com.app.los_pdapp.Fragments.PD.Applicant.DetailView.onViewCreated(DetailView.java:65)
04-25 14:28:43.024 21208-21208/com.app.los_pdapp W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
```

My method for reading the bitmap is :

```
public static Bitmap readBitmap(Context context, String name) {

        Utility.printMessage("name of file..."+name);


        String name1 = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        Utility.printMessage("name of file..."+name1);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(name);
        Utility.printMessage("*************** : " + b);
        if (b != null)
            return b;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(name);
//            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(name);
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            fis.close();
            return b;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utility.logException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried using the url connection stream and decoding the bitmap but this solution does not work.
Hence can any one suggest whats wrong in above code?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27054423/8770539. This might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`context.openFileInput(name);` doesn't accept paths, only filenames. Use `FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(new File(name).getName())` instead

Comment: earlier you said we can't use context.openFileInput?

Comment: There is no method as getFileName()

Comment: Meant getName()

Comment: `openFileInput` only accepts file names, but since your file is in your app's private storage it's the only way to access it. If the file was somewhere else you could use the `FileInputStream` method

Comment: Okay let me try