# How to open a file that is already created in Android Phone SD Card

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have already created a file and I want to open it. After creating the file with some common opening text, I call the method, writeValuestoFile(String fname) where fname is the File Name. In the method, I would like to open the file I already created through another method and just update it. But, I am InvalidArgumentException. I am doubting if my path I am specifying is correct or not. Input will be highly appreciated. This is my method call.

```
public void writeValuestoFile(String fname)  {
String rec_x_string = Float.valueOf((x_updated)).toString();
        String rec_y_string = Float.valueOf((y_updated)).toString();
        String rec_z_string = Float.valueOf((z_updated)).toString();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput("sdcard/Accelorometer Readings/"+file_name, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            OutputStreamWriter write = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
            String newline = System.getProperty("line.seperator");
            try {
                write.append(newline);
                write.append(newline);
                write.write(rec_x_string + "        " + rec_y_string + "        " + rec_z_string);
                write.flush();
                write.close();
                fout.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;

    }
```

This is my Logcat for the exception:

```
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File sdcard/Accelorometer Readings/null contains a path separator
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1674)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:420)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at com.example.hw02_devarajan_q1.MainActivity.writeValuestoFile(MainActivity.java:241)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at com.example.hw02_devarajan_q1.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:91)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
02-08 05:57:49.869: E/AndroidRuntime(24818):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does LogCat say?

Comment: Also, is openFileOutput, the function to call to update a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use hardcoded `sdcard/` - this is **WRONG** approach for long time not to mention it may simply not work on all devices. You should be using `Environment` class' methods like [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) to get the right directory as documented here. [You should read this chapter of documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to see how this should be done the right way. Do not forget about proper permissions as well.

Also: `fname` argument is not used in your `writeValuestoFile()` function at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I know how to use it to create a new file. But how do you use it to open an existing file. I am having the filename passed as input to the method.

Comment: I tried this but still the same problem openFileOutput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Accelorometer Readings/"+fname

Comment: you are not using function argument at all

Comment: I don't get you. Can you explain what you are trying to say? I am new to I/O in Java, so I am sorry if I am asking something elementary.

Comment: Okay, I understand that the openFileOutput cannot have path as an input. But if I cannot use it, can anyone tell me how to open an existing file provided I have the filename with me?