# android: error when displaying .txt file in textview

Tags: java, android, itext

I am working on android app and part of it is to import a PDF file from SDcard and then display it in text view. I am using itext to create a .txt file from the pdf. I am having a problem when displaying the content of the .txt file in text view. can anyone help please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openFileInput()` will not accept path separators.('/'). It accepts only the name of the file which you want to open/access. So change the statement,

```
InputStream in = openFileInput(String.valueOf(filepath));
```

to,

```
FileInputStream in = FileInputStream(filepath);
```

Also there is no need to convert `filepath` into `String` as `FileInputStream` can accept `File` types.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for `ContextWrapper.openFileInput()` specifically says you cannot provide a path.

```
name   String: The name of the file to open; can not contain path separators.
```

`openFileInput` is for dealing with private files, which I think means files your app creates for the purpose of your app, so it would be saved in your private app data directory.

I didn't read through your entire code snippet, but assuming you are instantiating the `File` object correctly and you just want a `FileInputStream`, you should be able to just instantiate one directly:

`InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filepath);`

Making sure your app has permission to access files.