# Checking if I can access a file in Android file file system

Tags: android, file, sysfs

I'm trying to cat files in Android sysfs, and first I'd like to check if the files exist, and if they are accessible. I'm trying the first step with the following Java code:

```
String filePath = "/sys/some/path/to/some/file";
try {
  File file = getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath(filePath);
  if (file.exists()) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At run time, I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /sys/some/path/to/some/file contains a path separator

What am I doing wrong, and how can I check if a file in sysfs is readable?

Comment: Follow this thread
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contains a path separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator)

Comment: OK, that thread suggests using a FileInputStream instead of File object. How then can I check for read access to a FileInputStream object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using vivek's suggestion to use FileInputStream, and then checking for exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
  String fileDirectory = "/sys/some/path/to/some/";
  String fileName = "file";
        try
        {
            File file = new File(fileDirectory, fileName );

            if (file.Exists()) {                    
                // do something
            }
            else
            {
                // do something else
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }
```