# Android Processing Filepath issues

Tags: android, processing

I have a Android Processing sketch that used to work a few years ago but I need to update it and can't get it to run. It seems like there is a problem with having the path in the filename string but this used to work..

Any idea how to work around this problem? Ideally I would like to keep my code as is and figure out how to make it run on my device.

Thanks

Phil

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 787
    Process: processing.test.


pixelpetal_v09, PID: 1579
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File sequences/allseq_pixelData/pixelData00000.png contains a path separator
        at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2366)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getFileStreamPath(ContextImpl.java:1120)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFileStreamPath(ContextWrapper.java:191)
        at processing.core.PApplet.sketchPath(Unknown Source)
        at processing.core.PApplet.createInputRaw(Unknown Source)
        at processing.core.PApplet.createInput(Unknown Source)
        at processing.core.PApplet.loadImage(Unknown Source)
        at processing.test.pixelpetal_v09.pixelpetal_v09.loadImageSequence(pixelpetal_v09.java:96)
        at processing.test.pixelpetal_v09.pixelpetal_v09.setup(pixelpetal_v09.java:116)
        at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
        at processing.opengl.PGLES$AndroidRenderer.onDrawFrame(Unknown Source)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963535/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contains-a-path-separator

Comment: Can you post the code that's causing the error too?

Comment: `
for (int i=0; i<numFrames; i++) {
    String imageName = "sequences/" + basename + "_pixelData/pixelData" + nf(i, 5) + ".png";

    imageSequence[i] = loadImage(imageName);

    println("Image "+imageName+" was loaded as "+imageSequence[i]);
  }`